# How to change a value in a line of a file

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am using python 3.9.6. I have a file which includes the following line in the file: reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [3.547000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0]). I want to change the value 3.547000e+15 to 2 times this value(7.094000e+15) in this line. So:

reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [3.547000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0])

to

reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [7.094000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0])

I wrote a code that works, but I have to manually replace 3.547000E+15 with 7.094000e+15 using this code.

```
data = []
with open("chem_copy.cti","r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
print(data[2027])
 
with open("chem_copy.cti", "r")as f:
    with open("chem_copy2.cti", 'w') as new_f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f,0):
            if i == (2027):
                new_line = line.replace("3.547000e+15","7.094000e+15")
                new_f.write(new_line)
                print(new_line)
            else:
                new_f.writelines(line)
```

I want to write a code that can find the value 3.547000e+15 as being the first value within the brackets [ ] of this line and change it to 2x this value. I do not want to have to manually write the number I want to replace and what to replace it with. Is there a way for me to do this? I have attached a dummy code with what I want my code to do. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
#Dummy Code
data = []
with open("chem_copy.cti","r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
print(data[2027])
 
with open("chem_copy.cti", "r")as f:
    with open("chem_copy2.cti", 'w') as new_f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f,0):
            if i == (2027):
                num1 = first variable in brackets
                num2 = 2*first variable in brackets
                new_line = line.replace("num1","num2")
                new_f.write(new_line)
                print(new_line)
            else:
                new_f.writelines(line)
```

Comment: Do you want it to change the file or create a new file?

Comment: Look into regex, regex.sub will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `eval()` function to change a string element to a float element, and the `str.find(substr)` function will return the first place where your substring appears.

```py
data = []
with open("chem_copy.cti","r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
print(data[2027])
 
with open("chem_copy.cti", "r")as f:
    with open("chem_copy2.cti", 'w') as new_f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f,0):
            if i == (2027):
                num_begin = line.find('[')+1
                num_end = line.find(',', num_begin)
                new_num = eval(line[num_begin:num_end])*2
                new_line = line.replace(line[num_begin:num_end], f"{new_num}")
                new_f.write(new_line)
                print(new_line)
            else:
                new_f.writelines(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - Use regex to capture the group, then convert it to float and perform your calculation then.

```
import re

data = []
with open("chem_copy.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    with open("chem_copy2.txt", 'w') as new_f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 0):
            if i == (0):
                num1 = re.search("\[(.*?),", line)[1]
                num2 = 2 * float(num1)
                new_line = line.replace(num1, num2)
                new_f.write(new_line)
                print(new_line)
            else:
                new_f.writelines(line)
```

I tested with a single line file, and both my files was txt, but cti should work the same.

Comment: Based on another answer - float could be replaced by evel when converting num1

Comment: using float does the same thing but it is way clearer what you are trying to do. Always use float in this situation

Comment: @JeanPierreNell. Thank you so much for your reply. When I ran the code with my cti file, I got the following error: replace() argument 2 must be str, not float. So, I just added str(num2) to your code and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Happy to help @AVK !

Answer (score 0):

You're after a regular expression, something like:

```
import re

test = """
some text
   reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [3.547000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0])
more text
"""

regex = r"(?<=reaction\('h \+ o2 <=> o \+ oh', \[)-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:e[\+-]\d+)?)?(?=.*]\))"

result = re.sub(regex, lambda m: f'{float(m.group(0))*2:.6E}', test)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
some text
   reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [7.094000E+15, -0.406, 16599.0])
more text
```

This assumes your number will always have digits before the decimal point, optionally have them after the decimal point, optionally have an exponent suffix and may be negative. Of course, you could make it more fancy still.

The part that really matches the number:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:e[\+-]\d+)?)?
```

The rest is just lookbehind and lookahead for the rest of the expression. You could of course just use far simpler criteria to match whatever was found between an opening bracket and a comma, assuming that can't appear anywhere else in the source text.

Since only the number itself is matched, the replacement works:

```
lambda m: f'{float(m.group(0))*2:.6E}'
```

This is just a lambda function that takes the outer matched group (the entire match), turns it into a floating point number, multiplies by two and then formats the result as floating point representation with 6 decimals in scientific notation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I forgot to mention that not all my reactions start with 'h \+ o2 <=> o \+ oh' but that was completely my mistake. Thank you very much for your response and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using regular expressions with the `re` module. This module allows you to find certain strings in your text so you could easily figure out what you want to replace.

I would also have a function `double` that takes the old string and replaces it with a new one, being two times the number in it.

```py
import re

def double(number_string):
    number = float(number_string.group(0))  # turn the string containing the number into a number that we can do math with
    new_number = number * 2
    return '%e' % new_number  # turns the number into a string with scientific notation

with open("chem_copy.cti", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data[2027] = re.sub(r'(?<=\[).+?(?=,)', double, data[2027])  # update the line, more on this after the code block

with open("chem_copy2.cti", "w") as new_f:
    new_f.writelines(data)
```

Lets break down `re.sub(r'(?<=\[).+?(?=,)', double, data[2027])`:

- `re.sub(pattern_to_replace, replacement, string)` searches `string` for `pattern` and replaces that pattern with `replacement`
- the r before the pattern string means backslashes in the string will be treates as literal backslashes
  The pattern string `'(?<=\[).+?(?=,)'` searches for the number. Let's break it down:
- `\[` and `\]` match sqaure brackets
- `(?<=\[)` means the pattern you're looking for has an opening bracket before it
- `.+?` means the pattern consists of any characters until the comma, the question makes it "non-greedy" so it stops at the first comma rather than the last
- `(?=,)` means the pattern comes right before a comma

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and explanation. I ran your code and got this error: could not convert string to float: '3.547000e+15, -0.406'. I think somehow it's taking both the first and second values within the brackets.

Comment: @AVK you're right I edited the answer. I was missing the non greedy operator, meaning it was matching text until the last comma rather than the first (changed `.+` to `.+?`)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do what you want to do here. An easy solution (in my mind) would be to create a dict() of key/value pairs that you can use to substitute. Keys and values would be strings. The value corresponding to the key would be 2*key.  Then when you parse through the input file, you can check each line to see if a key is in it, and, if so, make the substitution.  Something like this could work:

```
substitute_dict = {"3.547000e+15": "7.094000e+15"} # add other k/v pairs as needed
with open("chem_copy.cti", "r") as f:
    with open("chem_copy2.cti", 'w') as new_f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            for k, v in substitute_dict.items():
                if k in line: # this can be tighter it needed
                # if line.lstrip().startswith(f"[{k}"): # this is tighter
                    new_line = line.replace(k, v)
                    new_f.write(new_line)
                    print(new_line)
                else:
                    new_f.write(line)
```

The performance of this will be far from optimal, but it will work.

If you don't want to use a dict for substitution values but just want all the initial values doubled, something like this should work:

```
with open("chem_copy.cti", "r") as f:
    with open("chem_copy2.cti", 'w') as new_f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith("["): # error checking never hurts
                num_value = line[1:].split()[0]
                try:
                    val = float(num_value)
                except ValueError:
                    val = 0
                doubled_val = f"{2*val:e}"
                new_line = line.replace(num_value, doubled_val, 1) # only replace 1st instance
                new_f.write(new_line)
                print(new_line)
            else:
                new_f.write(line)
```

Comment: At some point, somewhere, you have to identify which numeric strings you want to replace. You can do this mathematically, by converting the strings to numbers and then doing a mathematical comparison. Or you use strings and do a string comparison (as I have done). Which approach you take is determined by how you want to accomplish your task. If you only need to substitute a discrete number of values, strings can work. Even if you do need to process a range of values, strings might still work, since you can compare numeric strings.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. Could you elaborate a bit more or show an example on converting strings to numbers? I have about 500 of these lines to change and I have to do it in a continuous loop one after the other. All have different numbers for the first value between brackets and all need to be changed to 2 x their value, so I do not want to have to manually write any numbers, only specify that for each line I want that first value between brackets changed to 2 x the original value. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: convert strings to floats using float(), and convert floats to strings using f-strings with ":e", as in f"{value:e}". See second example above.